# quadratic algebra word problem

Tags: calculus

Can someone please help me with this problem I have had an attempt at it but don't think i'm anywhere near right.

A ship covers 480 miles at a uniform speed. If her speed had been 4 knots less, she would have taken 4 hours longer, calculate her speed

4s - 4 = 480?

The answer to this question is 24 knots.

can someone please help me out with the working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v \equiv$ velocity and $T \equiv$ travel time. We have

\begin{align*}
v T & = 480 \quad \quad (1) \\
(v - 4) (T + 4) & = 480 \quad \quad (2)\\
(2) - (1)\implies 4 v - 4T - 16 = 0 \\
\implies v - T = 4
\end{align*} 
So $T = v - 4$. You can now substitute in $(1)$ to get $v^2 - 4v = 480$ which has (positive) solution $v = 24$.

By the way, I disregarded physical units. Physicists would probably slap you in the face if you presented it this way.